# Clear queue in jquery doesn't work for delayed show hide on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The best is to check out the example in http://jsfiddle.net/jDn7X/

```
$(".container.a1 div").hover(function(e){
    $(".popup").show(300).css({top: (e.pageY + 15) + "px",left: (e.pageX + 10) +"px"});
},function(){
    $(".popup").hide(300);    
});
```

The popup keep appering when I move over the div array.

```
<div class="container a1">
   <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

With **clearQueue** the behaviour is random.

What's the best way to clear the previous jquery timers?

Comment: his fiddle showing the example is: http://jsfiddle.net/jDn7X/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) :

```
$(".container.a1 div, .container.a2 div").hover(
    function(e){
        $(".popup").stop(true,true)
                   .show(300)
                   .css({top: (e.pageY + 15) + "px",left: (e.pageX + 10) +"px"});
    },function(){
        $(".popup").stop(true,true)
                   .hide(300);    
    }
);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jDn7X/2/)

I would probably do something more like this (see comments) :

```
$(".container.a1, .container.a2").on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $(".popup").show(300);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(".popup").hide(300);    
    },
    mousemove: function(e) {
        $(".popup").css({top: (e.pageY + 15) + "px",left: (e.pageX + 10) +"px"})
                   .text('hovering : '+$(e.target).index());
    }
});
​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jDn7X/5/)

Comment: +1 I was writing the same.. but the effect is lost when you hover on multiple elements quickly.

Comment: @Vega - yeah, but not sure how the OP intended it. I would probably attach the popup handler to a wrapper element and just change the popup content on movement between squares to avoid the annoying popping up stuff, but the question does'nt really mention that ?

Comment: I keep with solution 1, the flickering among div change is intended.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think that this is the wrong approach to a tooltip over many small elememnts in close proximity.

I think the better approach is to .hover the whole .container and then change the content onmouseenter of each element.

http://jsfiddle.net/lathan/jDn7X/1/

Comment: I like your solution but in fact the flickering among div change is intended. Thanks anyway for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

Do a quick `.stop()` ([more information found here](http://api.jquery.com/stop/))

`$(".popup").stop().hide(300);`

This stops all previous animations from happening on the object in question.

http://jsfiddle.net/jDn7X/4/